# How to open .eml files in the WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, email, webbrowser-control, openpop

I'd like to ask here, how can I open a .eml file, located in the file system, in a WebBrowser control. Here's what I've at this moment:

```
string uri = Convert.ToString(myDataReader["Uri"]); //obtained the URI from a database query a few lines of code earlier


FileInfo file = new FileInfo(uri);
OpenPop.Mime.Message mensagem = OpenPop.Mime.Message.Load(file);

origem = mensagem.Headers.From.ToString(); //origin of the email
destino = mensagem.Headers.To.ToString(); //destiny
assunto = mensagem.Headers.Subject.ToString(); //subject
conteudo = mensagem.MessagePart.Body; //message body
```

I'm using OpenPop.Net to get the messages from the POP3 server in another form, and I need to know how to get the HTML part of those messages...

Thanks in advance!

João Borrego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the [examples for OpenPop.Net](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php)? Specifically you should check out the ["Find specific parts of an email (text, html, xml)" example](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSpecificParts.php).

There is a [introduction](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/emailIntroduction.php) to how email works on the website as well. This might be helpful in understanding how OpenPop.Net is built since it evolves around how emails are structured internally.

Comment: Yup it helped, however, they don't show how to do something like this: mensagem.FindFirstHtmlVersion().GetBodyAsText(); had to find out by myself... Thanks =D